# AWS Amplify currentAuthenticatedUser is null after FB Login in React Native, but when app is reloaded, currentAuthenticatedUser returns valid user

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate Facebook login into my React Native app.

I have been able to implement successfully the Auth.signIn() method, and I can consistently retrieve the user using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().

However, when I use Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() after getting the code from the Facebook login, it returns null.

What's more, when I reload the app, Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() returns the user as expected.

I don't understand why, after I create a user session with the tokens, it does not recognize that I have an authenticated user.

Here is my code:

```
getTokenbyCode = async (code) => {
      const details = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code,
        client_id: userPool.clientId,
        redirect_uri: AuthSession.getRedirectUrl()
      }
      const formBody = Object.keys(details)
        .map(
          key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(details[key])}`
        )
        .join("&");

      await fetch(
        tokenURL,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
          },
          body: formBody
        }
      )
        .then(async (res) => {
          let tokenRequestJson = await res.json();
          const IdToken = new CognitoIdToken({ IdToken: tokenRequestJson.id_token });
          const AccessToken = new CognitoAccessToken({ AccessToken: tokenRequestJson.access_token });
          const RefreshToken = new CognitoRefreshToken({ RefreshToken: tokenRequestJson.refresh_token })
          try {
            let userSession = new CognitoUserSession({ IdToken, AccessToken, RefreshToken });
            const userData = {
              Username: userSession.idToken.payload.email,
              Pool: userPool
            };

            cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
            cognitoUser.setSignInUserSession(userSession);
            cognitoUser.getSession(async (err, session) => { // You must run this to verify that session (internally)
              if (session.isValid()) {

                // EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO HERE <!---------------->

                let cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
                this.setState({user: cognitoUser})

                this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthLoading', {user: cognitoUser})
              } else {
                console.log('session is not valid: ', session);
              }
            })
          }
          catch (FBSignInError) {
            console.log('FBSignInError: ', FBSignInError)
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error: ', error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out but only by brute force, so if someone wants to tell me WHY this works, I'd be glad to hear it.

My guess is that by setting the user session using the Auth module, it stores the user tokens in the right place so that the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser can pick it up.

```
  cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.setSignInUserSession(userSession);
  let authUser = Auth.createCognitoUser(cognitoUser.getUsername())
  authUser.setSignInUserSession(userSession)
```

Creating the cognitoUser may not be necessary, but it's working, so I'm good with it.